# I am getting an error on getInputStream() and getOutputStream methods?

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

My goal is to convert an array of floats to a string array and send it to a remote server in my house via a POST request. I am not using sockets.

```
URL url = new URL("http:// (destination of the remote server) : (port)");
 URLConnection connection =  url.openConnection();
```

This is how I am writing my getInputStream() and getOutputStream method and every time I run my code my activity crashes.

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Everything works but my activity comes to `getOutputStream()` and it crashes. I tried commenting out the `getOutputStream()` part then it came to `connection.getInputStream()` and crashed.

What could be the reason why this isn't working?

StackTrace:

```
                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hfad.viscosity/com.hfad.viscosity.ProcessData}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:436)
                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
                                                                        at com.hfad.viscosity.ProcessData.onCreate(ProcessData.java:110)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: Plesae add the stack trace of the crash!

Comment: Could you check if the `new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());` is even returning a value?

Comment: Do the networking on the background thread.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time trying to send anything via http. How do I do that?

Comment: Please format this illegible mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are attempting network activities on the main UI thread for the Activity instead of a background thread. It is required for any activity that involves blocking I/O or heavy processing including network activity to happen on a background thread. You would hence want to use the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) functionality to achieve this use case.

Refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860538/android-http-post-asynctask) for an example

The second thing is that to perform Internet access from your app you need to provide Internet access permissions to your app. Refer to this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application) that should help you on how to go about providing this permission.

If you are facing any problems even after performing the above steps, then it is recommended that you post your entire source code (if possible or an equivalent example) so that more folks can help you out.

Comment: That one does it for HttpClient which is deprecated now. Do you have any idea how it can be done using HttpURLConnection?